# Double slash issue when passing URL variable to "open" command

Tags: bash, macos

I have a URL value stored in a variable, and I want to display it in the default web browser. When Attempting to do that, the "open" command doesn't recognise it as a valid URL because the double slash ("//") after the protocol prefix is replaced with a single slash. How can I prevent this replacement?

```
users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ echo "$invurl"
"https://xxx.xxx.com/projects/1291644-xxxv/builds/8504742/invite"
users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ 
users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ 
users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ 
users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ 
users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ open "$invurl"
The file /Users/user/"https:/xxx.xxx.com/projects/1291644-xxxv/builds/8504742/invite" does not exist.
users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$
```

Comment: First of all a backslash is "\". The `open` command without parameters is only for file system paths. You could use `open -a /path/to/browser $invurl`

Comment: I have edited the question, Thank you for this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with slashes, it has to do with `$invurl` containing `"` quotes! The `echo` should not output the quotes; since it is outputting quotes, that means your URL is actually `"https://..."`, including quotes. That causes it not to start with `https://`, which causes it not to be interpreted as a URL. The shell is looking for a directory called `"https:` in the current directory and normalises the double slash away.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't think about it. This URL is fetched from a JSON response and it has quotes, as you wrote.